# Tailwind CSS grid gives 3 rows instead of 3 cols but works with grid-cols-6 only

Tags: css, grid, tailwind-css

I wanted to have 1 row and 3 columns inside it. So I have created 3 divs inside a grid div which has a class of "grid-cols-3" but I got 3 raws and 1 column instead.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-3">
    <div> Col 1 </div>
    <div> Col 2 </div>
    <div> Col 3 </div>
</div>
```

Then I got

[image: grid-col-3]

But when I have changed the "grid-col-3" to "grid-col-6" it worked!

```
    <div class="grid grid-cols-6">
      <div> Col 1 </div>
      <div> Col 2 </div>
      <div> Col 3 </div>
   </div>
```

Then I got
[image: grid-cols-6]

I'm self-taught and do not have any great mentors. I know how to do it using CSS like "grid-template" but I'm using tailwind for faster deployment with Laravel and Livewire.

Comment: Your first example works fine in Tailwind Play so something else is going on with your layout https://play.tailwindcss.com/lNVMhy4i6Y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you test your code in [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/cdFmNjz5dV) you will notice that works fine (as expected), so there might be some **CSS** that override this class: `grid-cols-3`. You should check that.

However I had a similar issue with **Laravel Livewire** I checked the built in css files and I noticed there is this class defined: `.md\:grid-cols-3` so in my case this worked out:

```
<div class="grid md:grid-cols-3">
    <div> Col 1 </div>
    <div> Col 2 </div>
    <div> Col 3 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Gustavo, I noticed that tailwind was not properly loading in Livewire. I reinstalled tailwind and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Laravel Breeze and had the same problem. grid-col-1, grid-col-2, grid-col-4 worked but grid-col-3 wouldn't.

If regenerate the CSS by running `npm run dev` it works. Tailwind uses a plugin called purgecss so I think that was the cause. Very frustrating bug to locate

Comment: Thanks. This helped me. In my case, I was creating class dynamically so tailwind was not generating CSS for md:grid-cols-${itemPerCol}. So I updated tailwind config to have safelist: ["md:grid-cols-3"], and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem in next.js/tailwind @paddys_1 answer gave me the right hint. And I solved it by adding

```
<div className='grid grid-cols-3 hidden'><div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div></div>
```

somewhere in the body tag.